# Button value reset after reload page

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.3

I want to use one button for two language. when button value is English content will show in other language and vice-versa. but button value always set to English after page reload. i am using laravel 5.3

html code:

```
<input type="button" name="locale" id="languageSwitcher" href="{!! url('lang') !!}" class="btn btn-round btn-primary" value="English">
```

javascript code:

```
$("#languageSwitcher").change(function () {
    var locale = document.getElementById("languageSwitcher").value;
    if (locale == "English") {
        lang = "en";
        document.getElementById("languageSwitcher").value = "Bangla"
    }
    else if (locale == "Bangla") {
        lang = "bn";
        document.getElementById("languageSwitcher").value = "English"

    }
    var _token = $("meta[name=_token]").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/language",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {locale: lang, _token: _token},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (data) {

        },
        beforeSend: function (data) {

        },
        complete: function (data) {
            window.location.reload(true);

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
<input type="button" name="locale" id="languageSwitcher" href="{!! url('lang') !!}" class="btn btn-round btn-primary" value="English">
```

You have to pass the value throught the controller using a variable, or looking for someway to controll that on the controller,  because on every page reload your value always will been readed from the input html tag value static on the view

Comment: you can also use a variable on the controller start it to "English" on the controller constructor and then update the value on button click post action

Comment: how to do that??i tried so many different ways but didn't solve my problem

Comment: ok i'll explain you, you declare a variable inside the controller, then on the controller constructor set it to "English", you prepare a method on the controller can be called changeLang() { if (lang.Equals("english")lang = "spanish";} and then in the routes config file add Route::get('changelang', 'Controller@changeLang')->middleware('auth'); so you can create a linkbutton pointing to '{{urlto::changelang}}'

Comment: this is my controller


class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function changeLanguage(Request $request){

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            if (!Session::has('locale')) {
                Session::put('locale', Input::get('locale'));
            } else {
                Session::set('locale', Input::get('locale'));
            }

            return Redirect::back();
        }

    }
}

Comment: if you want to use that global controller better set a session with language and in the view read value from session, the comunication between controller functions and view buttons is in the routes file with the example i posted before Route::get('changelang', 'Controller@changeLang')

Comment: <input type="button" name="locale" id="languageSwitcher" href="{!! url('lang') !!}" class="btn btn-round btn-primary" value="{{Session::get('lang')}}">

Answer (score 0):

when page is reloaded your code

```
<input type="button" name="locale" id="languageSwitcher" href="{!! url('lang') !!}" class="btn btn-round btn-primary" value="English"
```

runs again..it is quite obvious that the value is set to "English". if you want to meet your requirement then  try something that can hold the value like hidden input filed our global variables.

Comment: every time i post my problem in this site my brain works better than before..solve my problem. i just change my html code to this: 

<input type="button" name="locale" id="switchlang2" href="{!! url('lang') !!}" class="btn btn-round btn-primary" value={!!App::getLocale()=='bn' ?"English" : "বাংলা" !!}>
and magic happens